# Cryptic clue: Bum can't stop twitching in three directions?

Tags: crossword-clues

Just a silly crossword-type cryptic clue. 9 letters.

Comment: According to convention, should this clue include the question mark or is that just part of the title?

Comment: Not so familiar with the conventions. But the answer is not a question.

Comment: A question mark implies that the clue isn't "playing by the rules", such as "A wicked thing?" cluing CANDLE. Given that this clue reads much like a normal cryptic, and you say you aren't familiar, I'll assume the question mark doesn't belong.

Comment: I think your assumption is correct.

Comment: Regarding your edit: a crossword clue should have one single unique answer.

Comment: I think the 9-letter solution is correct given the question, then (if you get the 9-letter, you've got the 8-letter as well).

Comment: The existence of an 8-letter version means my thought of POSTERIOR (with "bum" as the def) is out :-)

Comment: Can we get a clarification please: is this a [tag:cryptic-clues] clue (i.e. the type of clue described in Deusovi's [Cryptic Clue Guide](//q/45984)), as the title says? Or is it a standard crossword-style clue written cryptically, as your tags and [this comment of yours](//q/84754#comment246073_84758) suggest? This difference is significant and important.

Comment: Having skimmed over Deusovi's guide, I see that to be a proper cryptic clue it lacks the definition bit. It's all wordplay.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer is...:

> analytics

Explanation:

> bum = anal, twitch = tic, can't stop twitching = tics, three directions = y-shaped, can't stop twitching in three directions = y-tics, anal + y-tics = bum can't stop twitching in three directions!

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a full answer, but just some pieces that might help lead to a collaborative solution.

The last part of the clue, "in three directions", makes me think of

> compass directions -- N, E, S or W. Specifically, three of those four letters in some order. And the "in" part makes me think something else is going to be inserted into the middle of them -- e.g., EN______W or N______ES.

As for "can't stop twitching", perhaps

> "twitching" signifies an anagram? In which case, we would want some six-letter word or phrase for "can't stop" that could be inserted into the blanks above.

And that would leave "Bum" as

> the literal definition.

Comment: None of that is right, unfortunately. I'm not a crossword person, so perhaps don't rely on familiar conventions such as a word hinting that an anagram is involved, I wouldn't be that sophisticated. Still, I think the clue has a good, straightforward answer. Is this a good time to leave an additional hint?

Answer (score 1):

If **bum** means

> ass

and **can't stop twitching** is

> a sideeffect of taking **steroids**

what can be found in

> three directions, because directions is an anagram of STEROID NIC

Then we have

> **ass** and **steroid**

which can be "twitched" to

> asteroids (9)

or

> asteroid (8)

Another clue could be

> bum means "travel, with no particular purpose or destination" Doesnt that fit good to asteroids?

Comment: Brilliant! Not my answer, though, except for the difference between 8 and 9 letters, which is the same as mine.